# How many playthroughs do I need to buy everything?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Since [there isn't enough money](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54445/is-there-enough-money-in-one-playthrough-to-buy-everything) to buy everything in one playthrough, and the estimated credits total in the game is at [around 800k](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54948/max-earned-cash/54950#54950), I'm trying to figure out how many playthroughs I'll need to be able to afford to fully buy/upgrade everything in the game.  But how much is that exactly?  If you sum up all upgrades/shop items (lets assume I pick up everything in the missions), how much money would it take?

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/54948/1134 and http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/54456/1134

Comment: There is a 5% discount you can get too. So when/if you get that would affect the amount you'll need.

Comment: I'd be willing to take an answer that's +/- 5% of the actual, mostly just to get an idea of how many playthroughs I'll need

Comment: Also, buying at the store directly versus buying from the Normandy also affect the price.

Comment: It should be very possible in two but I don't feel like doing all the math.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to get everything on the second play through. The reason for this is you should be able to buy everything from the stores in game with the 800k. The weapon upgrades, you could probably level them up some also, mainly stick with the main ones you use until you have spare cash for team mates weapons. On your second playthrough each time you pick up a weapon it will gain 3 levels automatically.

Example is the Saber assault rifle, you dont get that until the 3rd to last mission in cerberus HQ, so on your second play through you can only max it out at 7, as soon as you pick it up a second time it will automatically got to 10. For some of the weapons that you find earlier in the game, they can go from 5 to 8, so you only have to pay for 9 and 10. I do not remember the cost of upgrading the weapons from 8 to 10, I want to say 150k to go from 9 to 10.

Answer (score -4):

You need about 3 playthroughs to get everything. That's about one for every ending.

Comment: Why is it exactly 3?

Comment: should definately add more then a straight forward answer.